# What could be possible screen resolution for devices in between 1025px and 2048px?

Tags: css, hardware, screen, screen-resolution

What could be possible screen resolution for devices in between 1025px and  2048px?

I'm making a website which should be fluid between 1025px to 2048px. I think If we know the possible resolution of devices between **1025px** and  **2048px**

So i can use different media queries. I think there will not be more then 5 breakpoints.

**Edit:**

Mostly we always consider Width of resolution because height of webpage is always different.

Comment: Just because a screen has a certain width, doesn't mean the browser window is using the whole width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a listing of resolutions [here](http://www.latenighthacking.com/projects/monitorResolutions.html); however the reality is that the resolution can be *anything*. Just because a monitor may perform best at a given resolution does not imply the user will be operating the monitor at said resolution.

You could take the approach of biting off the most commonly used resolutions as outlined [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_resolution) that fall within your window.

**Width Height % of Internet Users**

- 1024 768 22.63
- 1366 768 15.63
- 1280 800 14.55
- 1280 1024    7.96
- 1440 900 6.92
- 1680 1050    3.75
- 1920 1080    3.70
- 1600 900 3.12

Comment: I thought there will be 4-5 different combinations between 1025px and 2048px

Comment: and Mostly we always consider Width of resolution because height of webpage is always different.